# cordova camera cancelled error after adding background mode plugin

Tags: cordova

aftre adding the adding background mode plugin in the cordova app camera functionality is not working gives camera cancelled error after capture.

Everything works on android 5+ phone. But android 4+ phone it fails. 
Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

My problem was resolved with next steps:

- After add platform android, access the directory from this platform, open `android.json`, edit the value from preference of name `AndroidLaunchMode`, add this value: singleTop.
- After in terminal run `cordova run android` (or ionic run android, if with this framework).
- I tried add the value `singleTop` direct in AndroidManifest.xml, but I saw this value be updated with another value (Ex.: singleInstance).

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH RONY, I did not expect this reason (mixing background mode plugin with camera) I just know it was working so spend all the day trying, I updated androidmainfest launchmode and thought it is not the solution, your comment saved my day.

Comment: I have comment here, changing to singleTop will not allow you to bring the app to foreground using moveToForeground function from background plugin.